# Adding image in title spaces using ggplot2

Tags: r, image, ggplot2

I am a data scientist who is relatively new to R. In many of the data vizzes I generate, stakeholders usually prefer to have some "branding elements" when I create charts and figures. Within ggplot2, fonts and color schemes appear fairly simple and straightforward. What I am struggling with is to include branding images outside of the chart area. More specifically, I am trying to produce the image below without considering fonts and color schemes. Ideally, I could shift the title and subtitle over several centimeters to the right, and snap an image just to the left of it.

**Is there any advice, or sample solution anyone can provide?**

[Figure I am trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn79T.png)

Here is the base code I am working with. I am using data within ggplot2, and the image is from the web.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# The image I am interested in embedding in ggplot figure
myurl = "https://pngimg.com/uploads/bmw_logo/bmw_logo_PNG19705.png"
z = tempfile()
download.file(myurl,z,mode="wb")

sampleImage = png::readPNG(z) %>%
  rasterGrob(interpolate = TRUE)

# Sample ggplot plot where I would like to embed image in "title spaces"
# image is saved as "sampleImage", I do not know how to integrate it below
plot = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Primary Title",
       subtitle = "Secondary Title") 


plot
```

[What I have created so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q14a.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `annotation_custom` to annotate your image and use `clip = "off"` in `coord_cartesian` to place the image outside of the plot area. You could slightly place the title and subtitle to the right like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)

# The image I am interested in embedding in ggplot figure
myurl = "https://pngimg.com/uploads/bmw_logo/bmw_logo_PNG19705.png"
z = tempfile()
download.file(myurl,z,mode="wb")

sampleImage = png::readPNG(z) %>%
  rasterGrob(interpolate = TRUE)

# Sample ggplot plot where I would like to embed image in "title spaces"
# image is saved as "sampleImage", I do not know how to integrate it below
plot = ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(title = "Primary Title",
       subtitle = "Secondary Title") +
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') +
  annotation_custom(sampleImage, x = 1, y = 38, ymax = 35.5, xmax = 1.8) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.07),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.07))

plot
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>